# Accessing the current state with useContext on the top level

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I have a Form that has a group of checkboxes, Radio buttons and a Button.

Each time I update the value of a checkbox or radio button it dispatches an event that updates my state.  I can see this state by clicking my button component: `<Button context={ExampleContext} />`

However,  I can't seem to access my state the same way in the parent container by adding the same code snippets as it just returns undefined, this is the same logic that I have inside my Button component, so I'm not sure why it's not working.

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what.  How do I go about accessing my `state` from within the parent container?

I also have a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-minsky-0i4yx

Thanks for any help!

```js
// This doesn't seem to work
const { state } = useContext(ExampleContext);
<button onClick={() => console.log(state)}>See State</button>
```

```js
import React from "react";
import Checkbox from "./Checkbox";
import Radio from "./Radio";
import Button from "./Button";
import { ExampleProvider, ExampleContext } from "./ExampleContext";

const { useContext } = React;

const Form = () => {
  const { state } = useContext(ExampleContext);

  return (
    <ExampleProvider>
      <Checkbox context={ExampleContext} />
      <Radio context={ExampleContext} />
      <Button context={ExampleContext} />
      <button onClick={() => console.log(state)}>See State</button>
    </ExampleProvider>
  );
};
export default Form;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `useContext` hook is not inside the `ExampleProvider` context Provider.

You can fix it like this

```
const Form = () => {
  const { state } = useContext(ExampleContext);

  return (
    <>
      <Checkbox context={ExampleContext} />
      <Radio context={ExampleContext} />
      <Button context={ExampleContext} />
      <button onClick={() => console.log(state)}>See State</button>
    </>
  );
};

const FormWrapper = () => {
  return (
    <ExampleProvider>
      <Form />
    </ExampleProvider>
  );
};

export default FormWrapper;
```

Look at [this blogpost](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react) if you need to learn about the best way to handle the state management with React context API.

Comment: That's great!  Didn't think I was too far off!  Thank you :)